# Facebook LogIn Crashes application

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I developed a game in SpriteKit and Swift 4 in which I integrated Facebook. My app supports iOS 9 or higher. And yes, I know camel case is recommended instead of snake case.

Lately, my application crashes at facebook login, around 90% of the time. The rest of 10% it works as intended. Can anyone point me what can cause this problem and how to fix it?

In `podfile` I included:

```
 pod 'FacebookCore'
 pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

In my AppDelegate I added:

```
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKLoginKit

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool
{
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: nil)
}
```

Also, my `.plist` looks like this.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb282293049303792</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>282293049303792</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Squares</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

But when I run the login code, the app crashes with this error.

```
func facebook_login()
{
    let login_manager = LoginManager()

    login_manager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self.view?.window?.rootViewController)
    {
        (result) in

        switch result
        {
            case .success(grantedPermissions: _, declinedPermissions: _, token: _):
                self.get_facebook_data()
                break

            case .failed(let err):
                print(err)
                self.show_error(type: "fb_login_failed")
                break

            case .cancelled:
                print("canceled")
                self.show_error(type: "fb_login_cancelled")
                break
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if the `result` is `success`, `failed` or `cancelled`, it still crashes on `AppDelegate`.

[image]

Comment: doesnt look like its anything to do with Facebook code, looks like its a racetime condition in one of your datasources

Comment: if i don't run the login function, my application never crashes.also, the login is in an intro scene, nothing is here except facebook login button.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by updating the phone to the latest `iOS 12.1.4`. Apparently the Facebook library crashed on the previous iOS version.